# Why is Git failing to update?

Tags: macos, git, osx-mountain-lion, updates

This is actual copy/paste from my shell:

```
machine:~ me$ brew install git
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/git-2.2.1.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring git-2.2.1.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
The OS X keychain credential helper has been installed to:
  /usr/local/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain

The "contrib" directory has been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/git-core/contrib

Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

zsh completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.2.1: 1356 files, 32M
machine:~ me$ 
machine:~ me$ git --version
git version 1.7.10.2 (Apple Git-33)
machine:~ me$
```

I can close Terminal and open it again, but the same Git version is shown.

Running `which git` returns `/usr/bin/git`. If I move that binary to `/usr/bin/git`, then run `git --version` again, it returns `git version 2.2.1`, but why does installing a new Git not replace the old one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no Mac/homebrew expert, but typically what happens is that when you install, it simply unpacks git to it's own, version specific, directory.  /usr/bin/git is likely a symbolic link to the actual git binary in said version specific directory.  All you would need to do in that case is unlink /usr/bin/git and recreate the link to the newer directory.  If I were to guess at the command, not knowing your directory tree, it would be something like this:

```
unlink /usr/bin/git
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.2.1/bin/git /usr/bin/git
```

Answer (score 2):

Give `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` a try. If it works add it to your .bashrc file